# AWS Aurora - load balance read operation between read replica and writer instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Aurora cluster has two endpoints: one for writes and the second one for reads (the endpoints that contains `-ro` prefix). When going through the [documentation about connection management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html) I learned that the read-only endpoint balances the connections between Aurora replicas. But it looks like it doesn't include the writer instance in this load balancing.

Is there a way to include the writer instance in the read-only (`-ro`) endpoint? In applications where 99% of the traffic is reading the data having a cluster with a writer and one reader (to have better availability in case the writer goes down) sounds like a waste of resources. In such case the writer will be idle in 99% of the time.

In the same documentation there is an info about the possibility to create the custom endpoint, but I'm wondering if that's the only possibility to solve about problem.

Comment: You can use writer for reading and writing.

Comment: The point of the writer is that the "writing" performance is not affected even if all `-ro` are overwhelmed. Now, if you use the writer endpoint to read as well, then it will become vulnerable to high read load.

Answer (score 0):

read-only instances in Aurora are mainly used as failover targets in Multi-AZ environments. So, if you chose this deployment, read-only instances are not a waste of resources.

However, you can only connect to your writer endpoint and directing to it both writes and reads from your application. There is the risk of overwhelming the writer instance with reads and degrading performances of the 1% of the writes.

The main point here is that if you have both readers and writer instances you should make use of them, since you still have it for high availability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually able to define a custom endpoint and use that. It will have load balancing between the two, so you could just use that for reading. We had a similar situation to yours and it worked quite well. From AWS documentation:
"A custom endpoint for an Aurora cluster represents a set of DB instances that you choose. When you connect to the endpoint, Aurora performs load balancing and chooses one of the instances in the group to handle the connection. You define which instances this endpoint refers to, and you decide what purpose the endpoint serves."

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html